# Wifi on X1 Carbon Gen4 stopped working on Ubuntu 16.04.1 after sudo apt-get update&&sudo apt-get install

Tags: wireless, network-manager, thinkpad

The networks options can be seen on the network options but it always says disconnected each time a network is selected

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.